How to include .Net framework version in .Net 3.5 dll?
I'm using Azure build pipelines to build my .Net 3.5 project and the .Net version is not included in the resulting .dll file. I'm using JetBrains dotPeek decompiler to inspect my dll file, and I believe an image shows my situation best. The below image shows a locally and remotely compiled dll file.

When I compile my project locally, the meta information about using .Net 3.5 is included in the dll (highlighted in yellow). When I use an azure build pipeline, the meta information about using .Net 3.5 is not included.
How do I ensure that the meta information about using .Net Framework 3.5 is included? I believe that the mscorlib reference version seen in the screenshot is a clue. I might be able to simply configure the build pipeline to use an older version of Windows, but I would rather use the latest version if possible.

.NET Framework 3.5 went out of support a very long time ago and isn't used anywhere in Azure. The oldest supported .NET Framework version is 4.6.2. When I compile my project locally you'll only get a 3.5 library if your project explicitly targets 3.5. It's way past time to upgrade to a supported version. 4.0 came out in 2010.

Can you provide the YAML for your build pipeline?

I attempted to build a .NET Framework 3.5 class library on local and in pipeline, both DLL files can display the '.Net Framework v3.5' on the dotPeek tool.

@BrightRan-MSFT only if you installed .NET Framework 3.5 separately. It's not installed by any of VS Installer's workloads, you have to install it as an individual component. Precisely because it's unsupported

@PanagiotisKanavos Becoming Feature on Demand and not enabled by default doesn’t mean .NET Framework 3.5 went out of support. Its end of life is in 2029 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework

The difference in mscorlib version indicates the assemblies were built against different target frameworks. So if you don’t reveal more of your project file and the build manifest, this question lacks of key information and cannot be answered.

I always forget this because the main reason to target 3.5 was Windows XP.

@FluffyBike, When you build your project in pipeline, you can try to add the msbuild argument '-p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v3.5' to the build task.

Hi guys, thanks for commenting. I'm afraid I can't share the yml pipeline. @Bright Ran-MSFT, I will try to add the 'p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v3.5'.

@FluffyBike, Okay. Go ahead to try '-p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v3.5' on your build task.

Okay, so I tried the '-p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v3.5', but there were no changes. What does work though is to change the pool: vmImage: 'windows-latest' to pool: vmImage: 'windows-2019'

The solution I ended up with is to downgrade the Windows Server version used to build from windows-latest (aka. windows-2022) to windows-2019. See this page for a list of available Windows Server versions and accompanying Visual studio versions.
In practical terms what I did was to change:
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

To:
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'


That's like throwing out the baby with the bathwater. There's nothing wrong with Windows 2022. If you want to build for a specific .NET Framework you have to ensure the correct SDK is installed. .NET Framework 3.5 is way, way too old and by now an optional install. 3.5 was nothing but 2.0 with extra libraries anyway, and 2.0 went out of support in 2011

@FluffyBike, Glad that you can find a way to resolve the problem. Maybe, you can accept this answer by yourself. It could be also helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar issues.
